# For loop runs twice but only for the first file

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, command-line

I wrote a simple `.bat` file that appends the string `"somethingnew"` infront of `.txt` files:

`for %%x in (*.txt) do ren "%%x" "somethingnew%%~nx.txt"`

But when I run it, it renames every file correctly, but at the end it renames the first file again.

For example, if there are 2 files `1.txt` and `2.txt` then this would happen:

- `1.txt` becomes `somethingnew1.txt`
- `2.txt` becomes `somethingnew2.txt`
- `somethingnew1.txt` becomes `somethingnewsomethingnew1.txt`

I found similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53487636/dos-batch-file-for-loop-runs-twice), but instead, the for loops run twice for every file, while here it runs twice for the first file, so I'm not sure what the solution is.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have short (8.3) file names enabled? if so, the 8.3 name of the first renamed file (probably `1.txt`, which becomes `somethingnew1.txt`, whose short name is something like `SOMETH~1.TXT`) also matches the pattern `*.txt` and might therefore be renamed twice, because most internal commands (like `dir`, `for`, etc.) that support wildcards match them against both long and short names, and because `for` does not build the file list in advance…

Comment: @aschipfl The `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation` in the registry has a hexadecimal value of `2`. So that means the 8.3 names are disabled?

Comment: Hm… I thought the value to disable is `1`… anyway, note that disabling just prevents future short names but does not clear already present ones…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple FOR-loop can fetch already renamed files, that's because the for loop take one filename, executes the block code and then take the next filename.

A FOR /F loop will take the complete output of the command, before executing the block code.

```
for /F "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b *.txt') do (
  ren "%%x" "somethingnew%%~nx.txt"
)
```